# WPF Application - Secure Storage of Customer Data

Tags: c#, database, wpf, security, storage

*New to Software Development/ Self taught. Please bear with me if i did not provide enough Information*

To finally finish a proper Project, i decided to tackle a Program for a relative to save and easily access contact information for their customers: e.g Name, Adress, Phone, Accounting related stuff.

I don't know much about software security, but i do know that you can Reverse engineer everything your program does, so how would you folks go about securing such sensitive Data?

This program won't be intended to be distributed to other people than this one person, but i do want to learn about this topic incase other ones are interested in using it.

I was thinking about .Net included storage, SQL or server based...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could go with **SQL Server Express** (database size = 10 Gb max).

Read about security here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/sql-server-express-security?view=sql-server-ver16
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sql-server-express-user-instances
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-tutorial-getting-started?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms

This article might help too: https://www.upguard.com/blog/11-steps-to-secure-sql

Comment: Alright i will try looking into that. One question though: Do the necessary files for the SQL Server remain in the Project environment for the user? Or did i missunderstand this type and it is also remotely hosted, like Azure?

Thanks for the quick referencing!

Comment: You can store a database instance on the same computer where your application is installed if your application is a standalone one. That also means you must include that instance in the setup project. Remote access to the database is also conceivable if you decide to separate it from the application. Your application will have to connect to your database that is installed on another server (on premise or in the cloud). The connection string should be stored in a configuration file in both cases described above. Take the time to design the architecture of your environment and your application.

Comment: Ok, thank clears things up for me! Thank you very much!